# paths are working on localhost but not working on production server [vue.js]

Tags: vue.js, filepath

I have a Vue website project. I developing it nicely on development server. Everything is OK, but paths are not working on Laragon and production server "file not found".

I tried these as prefix: '/', './', 'https://example.com/' and 'directly folder name/file.css'.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]]

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid importing scripts directly into the .html file but you should use javascript modules
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: But not only scripts. Also styles' path is not working too. How can do it I don't know. Why not working I don't know :(

Comment: it's the same, you have to use the import syntax also for css, json a so on